# Didn't find class "com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest" on path: DexPathList

Tags: exception, android-volley, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete, tlindexpathtools

I am using https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus library for implementing multipart in my project but this library conflicted with compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' dependency says " Program type already present: com.android.volley.BuildConfig" for this i included configurations {all*.exclude group:'com.android.volley'} im my build.gradle then it worked fine.But when i integrated places api in my app and starts seaching places ,the app crashes and
it prompt error  'Didn't find class "com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest" on path: DexPathList'.
Please help me!

Comment: may be its finding volley module from google placs api  and causes conflict?

Comment: Same with me . did you find any solution in place api

Comment: i solved- download volleyplus library from github and add this as library  module in android project. I have changed the volleyplus package name . com.android.volley to com.android.volley1 . Sync and solved